# Typescript modules resolving

Tags: javascript, typescript, commonjs

I've started a new ts project with a following file structure:

```
/src
    /dir1
        /dir2
            app.ts
    /dir3
        index.ts
```

I import module `app.ts` in `index.ts` in a such way:
`import app from '../dir1/dir2/app.ts'`

I want to write code with an alias `@` like that:
`import app from '@/dir1/dir2/app.ts'`
or at least like `import app from 'dir1/dir2/app.ts'`

Reading the articles and the docs I found that the problem can be resolved by adding `baseUrl` to `tsconfig.json` like that:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "es2020",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
}
```

However, the result file `index.js` requires `dir1/dir2/app`, and it's falling with a message: `Error: Cannot find module`. Can I handle this issue only with TypeScript settings, without Babel, Webpack and other large libs?

Comment: Alias is bad way, because when you would want to create another package and you would want to add this package as dependency, it will fail if other package has same alias for same file structure.

Comment: Okay. Is there the way to avoid relative imports, or any avoiding means 'alias'? Absolute pathes are good?

Comment: if you can use full package name instead of simple `@` for example, If the package is called `@company/support-app` then you can set `@company/support-app` as an alias to root, in this way, even if this package is added as dependency, its path will look like node style path. In node you can use absolute path starting with package name, you can configure your loader to do same.

Comment: I'm completely sure that my project will never be a dependency for others. Therefore I see `@company/support-app` kinda overwhelming. Is using `import app from 'dir1/dir2/app'` a good way? Is the other way to avoid multiple `../` sequences?

Comment: Note that all conversation is only about project modules, not from `node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `import app from '/dir1/dir2/app.ts'`

Might be useful https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Answer (score 0):

`baseUrl` will enable non-relative-looking module resolution relative to it.

If you use `"baseUrl": "./src"` then you can import any module within `/src` like this:

```
import app from 'dir1/dir2/app.ts' // this is still relative to the /src dir
```

If you want to use prefixes like "@" then you can use the `paths` compiler option which will re-map import locations relative to the `baseUrl`.

```
{
  "baseUrl": "/src",
  "paths": {
    "@dir1/*": ["./dir1/*"] // map imports from @dir1/ to ./dir1
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
import app from '@dir1/dir2/app'
```

[Relative and Non-relative imports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#relative-vs-non-relative-module-imports)

Comment: Is there option to convert resulting dist paths to relative ones: from `@dir1/dir2/app` to `../dir1/dir2/app`?

Comment: @avdotion, what do you mean? `../dir1/dir2/app` is the default import syntax for TS modules. Your question asked for a way to replace `../dir1/dir2/app` with `@dir1/dir2/app` or `dir1/dir2/app`

Comment: I want to convert absolute path into relative one during compilation, to write in `.ts` file `@dir1/dir2/app` and to get in dist `.js` file `../dir1/dir2/app`.

Comment: My answer will allow you to write `@dir1/dir2/app` in TS modules which will be compiled correctly to `../dir1/dir2/app`.

Comment: Is there common solution? `"paths": {"@*": ["*"]},` is returning `'@dir1/dir2/app'` either.

Comment: `"paths": { "@/*": ["./*"] }` would work for everything under `/src`

Comment: it doesn't work. Maybe because of `module` option? Please, help to figure out.